# Weird Error from Xcode Debugger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am using SQL lite database in my iPhone app. I have a refresh button on my Home screen and upon click of then refresh button I parse data from my web service and store the results into a SQL lite database. When I click on refresh button repeatedly I get an error. The error occurs after a variable number of clicks/refreshes each time.  The error is:

```
Failed to load debugging library at:
  /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/GDBMIDebugging.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/PBGDBIntrospectionSupport.A.dylib

Custom data formatters are disabled.

Error message was: 0xe00805 "dlopen(/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/GDBMIDebugging.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/PBGDBIntrospectionSupport.A.dylib, 10): image not found"`
```

After this error, my app crashes and when I logged the error it gives me an error "Unable to open database"

Please help me to resolve this error.

Thanks 
Sandy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the debugger is having a problem loading the data formatters that create the displays for various datatypes in the debugger window's variable display panel. If you've added any customer formatters, you should remove them.

Try running the program without the debugger and see if you get a crash. If so, the problem is in the app. If not, it's most likely in Xcode itself. I would test a dummy project and see if you get the same error.

It's possible there is hellish recursion somewhere in your code. I have seen that bring the debugger down but not with this error message.